# Create an array of even numbers from 2 to 20.Then using for loop and append function,insert numbers divsible by 7 from 30 to 50 to that array in pytho

Tags: python, arrays, append

I want to Create an array of even numbers from 2 to 20. Then using for loop and append() function,
insert all the numbers divsible by 7 from 30 to 50 to that array.

```
for i in range(2,20,2):
    for x in range(35,50,7):
     i.append(x)
print(i)
```

Comment: Try `[*range(2,21,2), *range(30, 51, 7)]`?

Comment: Or Just`list(range(2,21,2)) + list(range(30,51,7))`

Answer (score 1):

Modifying what you have:

```py
l = []
for i in range(2,21,2):
    l.append(i)
for x in range(30,51,7):
    l.append(x)
print(l)
```

Less code:

```py
l = list(range(2,21,2)) + list(range(30,51,7))
print(l)
```

I do 21 and 51 because by default the `range` function doesn't include the last number.